# getting npm issue while running the project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I'm getting the following issue all the time while going to run my project using `npm start`. Even after downgrading my node version to 8.4.0 (npm version 5.3.0) still getting the same issue. I know there are same questions present in stackoverflow as well as stackexchange with so many solutions given. I tried with all, like after removing the **node_modules** to run `npm cache clean --force` and then again `npm install`, the solutions are not working. I have shared the log below:

```
> subhojits-components@0.0.1 start 
/home/subhojit/Desktop/myproject
> node server/index

Unspecified environment, booting dev server
Booting dev server....
module.js:491
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:40:20
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/subhojit/Desktop/myproject/node_modules/express-handlebars/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! subhojits-components@0.0.1 start: `node server/index`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the subhojits-components@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Note**: I'm using graceful-fs version 4.1.15.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this? https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9355

Comment: yes @Jalil I checked this link. First of all I'm using ubuntu 18.04 not mac os and I checked with the possible solutions from there which is applicable for ubuntu but its still not of any help, getting the same issue.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I installed node specific version using nvm

Comment: Try with npm, that could help

Comment: dude before trying changing the version with nvm i tried with npm with the same version and at that time also it was giving the same issue. @Jalil

Comment: could you show the code where you're using?

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: try npm audit fix --force and clean cache. then try to run the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

`sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable`